# HTMLPurifier inserts \ before quotes

Tags: php, ckeditor, htmlpurifier

In the system I'm building I use CKEditor for writing posts. Then, when I send it to PHP I validate the html created from CKEditor with HTMLPurifier. The problem is that the HTMLPurifier adds \ before ". For example, the CKEditor produces:

```
<span style="font-size:36px;">
```

And after HTMLPurifier:

```
<span style=\"font-size:36px;\">
```

I'm using PHP 5.2. Why does HTMLPurifier adds these backslashes and what must I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not HTML purifier that adds the extra slashes, but your PHP configuration. Edit php.ini and [disable magic_quotes_gpc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

The linked manual suggests you to add the next setting to php.ini:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

If you are using Apache and can use `.htaccess` files, create one with:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you, I would never thought that this was causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stripslashes()` to get rid of them.

```
$string = '<span style=\"font-size:36px;\">';
echo stripslashes($string); // Output: <span style="font-size:36px;">
```